# How to set Button onClick event handler declaratively?

Tags: android, xamarin

Firstly, I apologise as I'm sure this has been asked before but I can't find an answer:

I am using Xamarin to write an Android application. How do I set an event handler declaratively?

Currently I have in my axml a button:

```
    Button
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/btnOne"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:text="1"
        android:onClick="btnOneClick"
```

That I would like to fire the method btnOneClick in my Activity.cs:

```
 using System;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;

namespace AndroidMacScanner
{
[Activity(Label = "MacScanner", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class Activity1 : Activity
{
    //int count = 1;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Login);

        // Get our button from the layout resource,
        // and attach an event to it
        //Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.MyButton);
        //button.Click += delegate { button.Text = string.Format("{0} clicks!", count++); };

        //EditText editText = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtPin);
        //editText.InputType = InputTypes;
    }

    public void btnOneClick(View v)
    {
        if (1 == 1) { };
    }
}
}
```

But when I click on the button I get a message saying the application has stopped working, with no other detail.

EDIT: Added my full code. The xml doesn't contain anything other than the above that is relevant. 
The logcat shows the following error: 
03-28 15:03:31.575 E/AndroidRuntime( 5178): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method btnOneClick(View) in the activity class androidmacscanner.Activity1 for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'btnOne'

So it can't find the event handler method...

What is wrong?

Cheers,

James

Comment: Post some your code and logcat. BTW, What you expect once the button clicks? To move to another activity or ?

Comment: That is all of the relevant code so far - I am just taking my first baby steps into Android :-). The event isn't being fired, so no breakpoint can be hit and so I don't see how to post anything useful using the stacktace? I am writing this using Visual Studio, by the way.

Comment: Worked out how to use the logcat and posted the relevant line above. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify 
Add the attribute [Java.Interop.Export] to your click handler method:

```
[Java.Interop.Export("btnOneClick")] // The value found in android:onClick attribute.
public void btnOneClick(View v) // Does not need to match value in above attribute.
{
   if (1 == 1) { };
}
```

Comment: I haven't tested this but this is the only answer that allows for setting the event handler declaratively, as in my example. The only time I've seen this so I hope it's useful to the next person with this question.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways that you can handle the click event on a view:

XML Method(The one in your post):

```
<!-- Declared in xml -->
<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonDoStuff"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_width="96dp"
    android:onClick="doStuff"/>

// In your activity
public void doStuff(View view){// must reference a view
    // do some stuff
    System.out.println("Doing stuff woo hoo!");
}
```

Activity OnClickListener // Not including in onClick in xml

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // handle clicks by view id
        if(view.getId() == R.id.buttonDoStuff){
            // Do stuff
        }
    }
```

Or you can create one on the fly for the button in code

```
    buttonDoStuff.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){
            // Do stuff
        }
    });
```

For only seeing that "the application has stopped working" on an emulator or actual device, that's whats known as an ANR (Application Not Responding) error, which occurs when the dalivk jvm kills the app process. If your developing with Eclipse or Android Studio you'll want to check your log cat for a detailed traced of the error. This will help you track down errors in the future.

Comment: Oh Sorry didn't realize you using Xamarin, my answer shows how to do this natively. Honestly I would recommend learning the native way. It will save a lot of headache later on and your apps will be much more robust and efficient.

Comment: I may come to learn Java yet, but as most of our code is back-end, if I can get Xamarin to work then I can use largely the same code for Windows Phone, iOS, Android and even Windows so it's definitely worth giving it a try! I'm afraid you're seeing the first stumbling steps ;-)

Comment: While I certainly agree that the hybrid app temptation to have a single base for each platform is certainly appealing at first glance, there are many x factors that you will find out that make things difficult. (from exp)

They include:
    - Cross browser compatibility issues just like the web
    - Ignoring of each platforms design guide lines. (What works on iOS may not be well suited for Android or Windows phone usability patterns) 
    - All the hybrid libraries are always one step behind the latest innovations on the native platforms. Lending to slow, broken, and just plain ugly apps.